# I'm trying something a little different

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, english, knowledge, language

Solve and combine:

1.1

```
Pull me from the lion's paw and place me on the page!
```

1.2

```
A matter of frequency - 10.3, 20.6, 41.2, 82.4, 164.8
```

2.1

```
#0047AB
```

2.2

```
.
..
.
```

2.3

```
75
```

2.4

```
A risky way to look inside?
```

3

```
Answer?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thoughts:

1.1

> Androcles and/or St. Jerome pulled a thorn from a lion's paw, depending on what you're reading. Thorn is an old English/Norse letter that corresponds to a modern 'th'

1.2

> Each number is double the one before. As M Oehm pointed out in the comments, the numbers posted describe the frequencies of an octave of the note 'E'.

2.1

> The hex colour code for cobalt. Cobalt has the chemical symbol 'Co'

2.2

> The letter 'r' in braille

2.3

> The ASCII code for 'K'? Perhaps more likely is that it's the atomic number of rhenium, symbol 're'

2.4

> A CT scan - uses x-rays, which could be seen as risky

3

> Exactly as it says - 'answer?'

Solution

> 'The Correct Answer?'

Comment: "Thorn" is also a Nordic and old English letter that corresponds to modern th. All frequencies are in Hz describe the note E. (An octave doubles the frequency.) hat would make the first word "The".

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to edit my answer to shamelessly steal it, but I'd suggest posting your own solution too, especially if you can work out part 2

Comment: Well done on the first one both of you.

Comment: Could risky way refer to a 'CT' scan?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I just had the same idea, so probably

Comment: @shree.pat18 Well done shree and logician

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat You got the CoRReCT answer